# To split data into 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data in one column sorted in ascending order. I want to split it in two columns. Check my table and expected output. The logic behind this is I want the 1st, 3rd, 5th row data in my first column and 2nd, 4th and 6th and so on.. data in my 2nd column.

My Existing Table:
**Table1:**

```
Col1
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Col1    Col2
2012    2013
2014    2015
2016    2017
```

Anyone with any suggestion as how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    Max(Col1) Col1, Max(Col2) Col2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1)- 1) / 2 as seq,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) % 2 = 1 THEN Col1 END Col1, 
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) % 2 = 0 THEN Col1 END Col2
    FROM yourTable) t
GROUP BY seq
```